# Css не работает

Tags: css

Вот код который я написал:

display: non;

Но почему-то блок не пропадает.

Comment: "non" - это "нет" по-французски

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы указали "non" а не "none" :D Проверьте ещё подключили ли вы CSS фалй ._.

Answer (score 1):

В CSS нет слова `non`, вместо него используется `none`.

```css
display: none; // этот код уберёт блок
```